# Absolute positioned elements in separate containers overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create "cards" for a project.

These cards would work like so:

In default every card only shows 3 lines of text. When an "extend card" link is clicked, the card gets absolute positioning and z-index to appear over other elements and opens down.

To prevent cards from moving when positioned absolute I put each in their own container.

This it the essence of my code: (Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fonorobert/5QaSu/))

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cardwrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/people/3" />
    <p class="lead">John Doe</p>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        <br/>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <br/>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p> 
    <a class="text-center card-button">extend</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cardwrapper {
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


.description {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
.description-show .description {
    max-height: 500px;
}
.description-show-position {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

```
$('.card-button').click(function () {
    var card = $(this).parent();
    var cardWidth = card.css('width');

    if (!card.hasClass('description-show-position')) {
        card.toggleClass('description-show-position');
        card.toggleClass('description-show');
        card.css('width', cardWidth);
    } else {
        card.toggleClass('description-show');
        card.css('width', cardWidth);

        card.on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function (e) {
            card.toggleClass('description-show-position');
        });
        card.off();
    }
})
```

I can't find a problem in the code, but it sometimes still overlaps with elements under the card. What do you think can cause this?

Is there a better way to do this than with the wrapper?

**EDIT:**

I realized that the `transitionend` event does't fire. Why do you think can that be?

Comment: I think the issue with the overlapping is that the height is missing in the cardwrapper class. For example, if you add a height of 350, they won't overlap anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code and now it seems to be working fine (you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5QaSu/7/

The changes I made:

- Added a height to the cardwrapper class (as specified in the comment above) to avoid the overlapping when collapsing the description:

  ```
  cardwrapper {
      width: 40%;
      position: relative;
      min-height:330px;
  }
  ```
- The transitionend event must be called from the parent instead of the card directly:

  ```
  card.parent().on('transitionend', function (e) {
      card.toggleClass('description-show-position');
  });
  ```
- Added a centinel variable to control that the `transitionend` is only called once (sorry, there must be a better way of doing this):

  ```
  card.parent().on('transitionend', function (e) {
      if (transition) {
          transition = false;
          card.toggleClass('description-show-position');
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, but I don't quite understand: why should the transitionend event be bound to the parent? `.card` has the actual transition, not the parent.
(Actually not even the card, but it's child, the `.description`)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting position absolute on all the cards: card1 would have top: 0, card2 top being the height of card1, card3 top = card1 + card2 etc.?